# How to check and split integer prefix in binary?

Tags: javascript

This is a kind of [formal specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification), not the implementation. The question is "how to implement?".

Suppose a 16 bits integer number `x`   (real case is 32 or 64 bits), `x=0b0010110010000000`, and suppose an array of prefixes to be checked, `prefixes=["001010111","010100","001011","1110"]` (here as strings to avoid confusion later).

When I  translate all (`x` and prefixes)  to string format (e.g. by `x.toString(2)`), there are a good solution:

```
 if (m = x.match(/^(001010111|010100|001011|1110)(.*)$/) 
     console.log("good number!","prefix="+m[1],"suffix="+m[2])
 else
     console.log("bad number...")
```

In the problem, I need prefix and suffix numbers as return.

But in real life, to performance and to stay all in the same format, I need **all** process in  [internal binary representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), **without** need of string translation step.

PS: the question is about the **"best binary solution"** (with less steps), **if** there are other  than the "naive solution" (with `prefixes.length` steps).

Comment: what's so freakin hard to just do `x.toString(2)` before you do the match?
you might need to use padstart though to have 0 in front to fill it up. otherwise.. no chance unless you shift the stuff down and do numeric comparisons. bitwise operations are what you searching for then

Comment: @GottZ, please see the condition, "without need of string translation step"... I am editing to be bold about the condition.

Comment: the condition is bogus unless you do bitwise operations. the fact you have .match there already shows you want to check a string and not a number. if you want to be strict about not using strings then don't use .match. i'm sorry for this rant style. don't take it as insult.

Comment: Where do all those leading zeroes come from? How wide are your integers (in bits)?

Comment: @Bergi, good question, I am using 32 or 64 bits integer representation... I edited, please check.

Comment: Hi @GottZ, you are wrong, is a very commom software engineering "problem statement"... But to avoid confusion I edited again, see the Wikipedia link to *formal specification*.

Answer (score 4):

You do prefix and suffix matching by using bit masks:

```js
const input =  0b00101011;

const mask =   0b11110000; // the first four bits of an 8-bit integer
//               ^^^^
const prefix = 0b00100000; // alternatively: 0b0010 << 4
//               ^^^^

if ((input & mask) === prefix) {
    console.log("good, suffix =", (input & ~mask).toString(2));
} else {
    console.log("bad");
}
```

For multiple checks, you'd simply run a loop over the different prefixes to be checked and their masks.

Notice that JavaScript bitwise operators work on *signed* 32 bit integers, don't forget to add in the necessary casts to unsigned (using `<<< 0`) if you expect that as output and are working with 32 bits. For more than 32 bits, best use typed arrays and compare them part by part.

Comment: Thanks, it is a solution!  But it is a kind of "brute force solution", there are no possible optimization using a kind of hierarchical partition of masks?

Comment: You mean like in a regex using `0(0101(0111|1)|10100)|1110` instead of `001010111|010100|001011|1110`? No, you cannot do that on the bit level (or at least it hardly would have an advantage). You might be able to do it your architecture's word size level (e.g. byte by byte on 8-bit processors), but given that you likely will run this on a 32 or 64 bit machine the if condition is just a single assembler instruction anyway.

Comment: Of course if you have lots of patterns (thousands and more), it might be beneficial to use a hierarchical approach (check the first byte to decide what to match in the rest, then check the second byte etc) instead of a linear loop over all prefixes. I would worry about this later though if you actually get performance problems with the naive solution.